# VS2013 CodedUITest on Java client

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to use Coded UI Test (Visual C#) to test a Java client application and I am quite new to this. 
Currently I have built enough to enter the set client which is built in Java. My problem is that it seems that I cannot use the UIMap Coded UI Test Builder to select any buttons within the application. When using the Assertions it selects the entire window instead of single buttons within the GUI.

I would rather code to reach my solution than using the UIMap recorder but unfortunately I cannot seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have searched long and far for a way to do this, and cannot find anything relevant, so please help!

Comment: Can you be more specific? UI Test Builder is not able to `see`specific controls? Meaning that it see your enitre app as a single control? If so then it means that Coded Ui cannot be used with your app.Since you cannot access parts of your app. The only way that it would work is to be position based (X,Y) with respect to that single control found...I wouldn`t recommend that option.

Comment: @ElieEl-Tawil Yes that is exactly what I mean. The entire app appears as a single control. If that is the case, I don't think I will pursue the position based solution. I'm currently searching for other ways to do this, and I would rather do it code-based. Do you have any other recommendations of methods of approach? Perhaps outside of VS2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tools like Sikuli...open source image recongition or EggPlant (not free).

We actually integrated sikuli in VS there is a library called SikuliIntegrator (SikuliModule.dll)

Or try anther tool like QTP or other open source to see if they can capture the controls better.

If the Java application you are testing is built by you or your team, you may ask them to change the architecture such that CodedUI could grab the controls...

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try out the SikulIntegrator and see if it solves my problem.